# jquery display loading text on keypress

Tags: php, jquery, html

I need the jquery script for the following

while typing inside the text field, the 'Load' text need to be displayed near the text field. 
If i stop typing the 'Load' text need to change as 'Del'
If click this 'Del' Text the text field should be cleared.

In the mean time i need to display the search result for the entered text.

For this i used the following script

```
 $("#lets_search").keyup(function() {
                var value = $('#str').val();
                $.post('db_query.php',{value:value}, function(data){
                    $("#search_results").html(data);

                });

                return false;
            });
        });
```

Here is the html part of the file

```
 <form id="lets_search" action="" style="width:400px;margin:0 auto;text-align:left;">
            Search:
            <div>&nbsp;</div>
            <div style="float:left; width:250px;">
            <div style="background-color:#fff; padding:3px; width:200px; float:left; border-left:1px solid #eee; border-top:1px solid #eee; border-bottom:1px solid #eee;">
            <input name="str" id="str" type="text" style="border:0px; width:150px;">
            <div style="float:right; padding-top:3px;" id="loader">Load</div>
            </div>

            </div>

         </form>
 <div id="search_results"></div>
```

In this `<div style="float:right; padding-top:3px;" id="loader">Load</div>`
I have to display the text (del, Loading etc...)

Please do the needful. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way to do this is with a setTimeout, like so:

```
var pTimeout = null;

$("#lets_search").keyup(function() 
{
    var value = $('#str').val();
    $('#loader').text('Loading...').unbind('click');
    if(pTimeout) clearTimeout(pTimeout);
    pTimeout = setTimeout(function () { GetResult(value); }, 50);
});

function GetResult(value)
{
    $.post('db_query.php',{value:value}, function(data){
        pTimeout = null;

        $('#loader').text('del').click(function () {
            $("#search_results").empty();
            $('#str').val('');
        });

        $("#search_results").html(data);
    });
}
```

There is always a better way of doing it, but must give you the idea.

PS I did not test the code :)

Comment: +1, I think the `.click()`/`.unbind('click')` approach is probably better than mine

Answer (score 0):

```
var searchTimeout = null;

$("#str").keyup(function() {

  // Clear any existing timeout
  if (searchTimeout) {
    clearTimeout(searchTimeout);
  }

  // Put "Load" text in
  $('#loader').html('Load');

  // Set a timeout for end of typing detection
  searchTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
    $('#loader').html('<a href="#" onclick="clearSearch();">Del</a>');
  }, 500);

  // Get the value from the text field and send it to the server
  var value = $(this).val();
  $.post('db_query.php',{value:value}, function(data){
    $("#search_results").html(data);
  });

});

// Clears the search box value
function clearSearch() {
  $("#str").val('');
};
```